# R - find row indices where each combination of factors occurs

Tags: r, subset

Suppose I have this data frame in R:

```
  Dim1 Dim2 Unused
1    A  100     3
2    A  200     6
3    A  100     7
4    A  100     4
5    A  200     8
6    B  200     9
7    B  200     2
8    B  100    10
```

I would like to find a fast way to **locate the row indices where each combination of Dim1 and Dim2 occurs** (the third column is useless here). It would be similar to `table`but instead of returning an integer with the count, I need the row indices (a vector) for each combination. I guess the output should be a list where each element is a vector (as shown in the "Rows" column):

```
Dim1 Dim2 Rows
   A  100 c(1,3,4)
   A  200 c(2,5)
   B  100 c(8)
   B  200 c(6,7)
```

Here I display only two factors but the general case may have n factor columns. The number of existing combinations (the result of `table`) is very sparse, so currently I first call `table` and then convert the result to a sparse matrix using package `slam` which already computes the unique combinations, but not their row indices.

Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Dim1', and 'Dim2', get the row index (`.I`) in a `list`, which we can extract.

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df1)[, list(Rows = list(.I)), by = .(Dim1, Dim2)]
res 
#    Dim1 Dim2    Rows
#1:    A  100 1, 3, 4
#2:    A  200    2, 5
#3:    B  200    6, 7
#4:    B  100       8
 res$Rows
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 1 3 4

 #[[2]]
 #[1] 2 5

 #[[3]]
 #[1] 6 7

 #[[4]]
 #[1] 8
```

Comment: So quick response, thanks so much!. Could you please explain the syntax of the "." (new for me) and the .I ? Actually I would like to get the result but not as a new column of the data frame (I depicted like that just for explaining my question) but as a list  of vectors (not strings). Thanks

Comment: @Pablo Updated the post.  Hope it helps

Comment: Cool! That's exactly what I wanted so I mark it as solved. I cannot find help about the .I function and the dot, could you please provide some reference? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pablo You can check the data.table [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and [FAQs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf)